# How to hide header and footer in webview in Flutter.?

Tags: flutter, dart, webview, hide

I'm beginner to flutter , I want to hide section of website in my flutter application . I added flutter `flutter_webview_plugin` in `pubspec.yaml` file and imported package to my feed.dart page. the  `flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavascript("alert('Hi, I just executed')");` is executed when i run the application. But `flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavascript("document.getElementById('header04-2j').style.display = 'none';");` i tried to hide header but its not working.
Bellow is the source code .. Please help .

```
enter code here
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';

class FeedPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  FeedPageState createState() {
    return new FeedPageState();
  }
}

class FeedPageState extends State<FeedPage> {
  final flutterWebviewPlugin = new FlutterWebviewPlugin();
  // alternatively you can define variable as var js = "YOUR_SCRIPT"; and use it inside evalJavascript

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavascript("alert('Hi, I just executed')"); // executed
    flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavascript("document.getElementById('header04-2j').style.display = 'none';"); // not executed
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    flutterWebviewPlugin.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WebviewScaffold(
      url: 'https://www.esdatech.com/',
      hidden: true,
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("ESDA")),
    );
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AI4R9.png)

Comment: If my answer helped you please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to your webpage not being loaded, and therefore the element not existing, at the point you call that method in your code.

A solution would be to wait until the page is loaded before attempting to remove the element using the `onStateChanged` stream.

```dart
StreamSubscription<WebViewStateChanged> _onStateChanged;

@override
void initState(){
  super.initState();
  flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavascript("alert('Hi, I just executed')");

  _onStateChanged =
    flutterWebViewPlugin.onStateChanged.listen((WebViewStateChanged state) {
      if(state.type == WebViewState.finishLoad) {
        flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavascript("document.getElementById('header04-2j').style.display = 'none';");
      }
    }
  );
}

@override
void dispose() {
  _onStateChanged.cancel();
  flutterWebviewPlugin.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}
```