# How to hide elements in webview in Flutter.?

Tags: flutter, flutterwebviewplugin

I want to hide section of website in my flutter application. I added flutter flutter_webview_plugin in pubspec.yaml file and imported package to my feed.dart page. the `flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavascript("alert('Hi, I just executed')");` is executed when I run the application. But `flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavascript("document.getElementById('header04-2j').style.display = 'none';");` I tried to hide header but its not working. Below is the source code.

```
class FeedPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  FeedPageState createState() {
    return new FeedPageState();
  }
}

class FeedPageState extends State<FeedPage> {
  final flutterWebviewPlugin = new FlutterWebviewPlugin();
  // alternatively you can define variable as var js = "YOUR_SCRIPT"; and use it inside evalJavascript

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavascript("alert('Hi, I just executed')"); // executed
    flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavascript("document.getElementById('header04-2j').style.display = 'none';"); // not executed
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    flutterWebviewPlugin.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WebviewScaffold(
      url: 'https://www.esdatech.com/',
      hidden: true,
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("ESDA")),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You are right. Sorry, I did not realize that there was a real URL in WebviewScaffold. By the way, there was a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63147034/how-to-hide-header-and-footer-in-webview-in-flutter